# Unable to fetch data from a Gitlab file - getting Cors exception

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

My requirement is fetching data from gitlab file through Angular application . We don't have any back end service to provide data. I have to get data directly from gitlab file. So I wrote below code.

```
private _jsonURL = 'gitlabpath/appdata.json';
constructor(private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient, private rd: Renderer2) {
this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
  this.objJs = data;
});}
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders({})
return this.http.get(this._jsonURL, {headers});}
```

But I am getting the following error

*

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

*

Please help me to fix this issue.

I didn't see any example for accessing gitlab file from angular code anywhare.

Comment: Not allowed to access Gitlab from a different frontend i imagine.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Gitlab is CORS blocked, except for their own domains. You probably calling it from localhost or another url which they do not support. You could try and make a backend system which acts as a proxy to retrieve the data, or you could use an existing one such as ['cors-anywhere'](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

For example:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://your-lab-url-here.com

There is a similar question on StackOverflow with a better explanation, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141).

Alternatively you could try and use the Gitlab API endpoint to see if you can retrieve your data that way, see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Comment: we don't have any back end system. So what shall I do?

Comment: You could try and use the second option in my reply, prefix your gitlab url with ' https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' to use that as a proxy. Keep in mind though this is not an ideal solution. Have you tried looking into the Gitlab api to see if they have endpoints that could suit your needs? See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/